# Create approval history report with object fields?

Tags: reporting, approval-process

I have standard approval process in opportunity. I want to create a report on approval process with opportunity.

I created a new report type with process instance and process instance node, but I need opportunity fields included with that approval process.

Is there any way I can do this with a report?

Answer (score 2):

If you need info of the Opportunity record of the approval, I think the standard report will not work.
There is an idea for that: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l7SVAAY

From this blog: http://cherfeldman.blogspot.com/2014/01/potential-solution-for-reporting-on.html

Potential Solution:
Add a custom object called “Approval History Reporting” to be a child object of opportunities through a master detail relationship.
Add the following fields to the custom object:

- Approval History Start Date/Time
- Approval History End Date/Time
- Approver – lookup to user
- Approver Changed to – lookup to user From
- Approval Status (picklist) – Submitted, Approved, Rejected, Recalled
- To Approval Status (picklist) – Submitted, Approved, Rejected,
- Recalled Approver Comments text field
- Age = formula field to    calculate Approval History End – Approval
  History Start, show number    in hours

How this object will work
Records will be inserted and/or updated when certain things happen.

Scenario 1: Opportunity is submitted for approval
Upon initial submission of an opportunity to an approval process a record will be inserted into the Approval History Reporting with the following fields populated:
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was submitted for approval
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status = Blank
To Approval Status = Submitted

Scenario 2: Opportunity is Approved by Approver:
Existing record with To Status of Submitted will update to have an Approval End Date/Time of the time the stage changed
New record will insert with the following information:
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was approved
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status =Submitted
To Approval Status = Approved
Comments = any comments entered by approver

Scenario 3: Opportunity is Rejected by Approver:
Existing record with To Status of Submitted will update to have an Approval End Date/Time of the time the stage changed
New record will insert with the following information:
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was Rejected
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status =Submitted
To Approval Status = Rejected
Comments = any comments entered by approver

Scenario 4: Opportunity is Recalled by User:
Existing record with To Status of Submitted will update to have an Approval End Date/Time of the time the stage changed
New record will insert with the following information:
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was Recalled
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status =Submitted
To Approval Status = Recalled
Comments = any comments entered by approver

Scenario 5: Approver is reassigned
Existing record that is submitted with no End time will have the Approver Changed To lookup update to the new approver

Scenario 6: Opportunity is Recalled and User Submits Again
New record will be inserted with the following information
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was submitted for approval
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status = Recalled
To Approval Status = Submitted

Scenario 7: Opportunity is Rejected and User Submits Again
New record will be inserted with the following information
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was submitted for approval
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status = Rejected
To Approval Status = Submitted

Scenario 8: Opportunity is Approved and user hits validation due to product/pricing changes and is forced to submit again
New record will be inserted with the following information
Approval History Start Date/Time – Time opportunity was submitted for approval
Approver – user selected as approver
From Approval Status = Approved
To Approval Status = Submitted

Comment: I need to create any trigger to insert record or Process builder is fine.And one more thing is how to achieve this for old records means all approved. @sfdc

Comment: Try in mass transfer approval request for old records to be approved